# how to get nested objects in django

Tags: django, django-views

models.py

```
class BuyNotes(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(to=Student, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    note = models.ForeignKey(to=Notes, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    buy_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    amount = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = [['note', 'student']]
```

views.py

```
def allNotesStudent(request):
    user = User.objects.get(username=request.session['user'])
    student = Student.objects.get(user=user)
    buy_notes = BuyNotes.objects.filter(student=student).get(note)
```

I know last line is wrong. how to get all **objects of note** that a student bought

Comment: user = request.user would do for getting current user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For only notes in queryset :**

```
buy_notes = BuyNotes.objects.all().filter(students__user = request.user).values('note')
```

Comment: if you want only note then , buy_notes = BuyNotes.objects.all().filter(students__user = request.user).values('note')